# JDialog lazy style code generation in Eclipse using WindowBuilder

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowbuilder

Is there a way to create JDialogs with Eclipse WindowBuilder and have the automatically generated code in lazy style? When I select Lazy in Preferences > WindowBuilder > Swing > Code generation, in JFrames I get lazy style code for all components. However, when I create a JDialog, the code is not lazy - it rather looks like this (note the parts for OK and Cancel buttons):

```
public class FactsDialog extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FactsDialog dialog = new FactsDialog();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public FactsDialog() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start creating a JDialog by WindowBuider, uncheck "Generate JDialog with OK and Cancel buttons" on the creation wizard (file> new> other> window builder> JDialog).